# No ejecuta mi progama en Java utilizando el IDE eclipse

Tags: java, android

No me corre el programa de Hola Mundo Al correrlo me aparece este error

> Errors occurred during the build. Errors running builder 'Java
>   Builder' on project  'HolaMundo'.   java.lang.NullPointerException

[image: intro[![introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Posible duplicado de [¿Cuál es la solución a todos los errores NullPointerException presentes, pasados y futuros?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/42977/cu%c3%a1l-es-la-soluci%c3%b3n-a-todos-los-errores-nullpointerexception-presentes-pasados)

Comment: Bienvenido a Stack Overflow en español, te sugiero que hagas el [tour] y, de paso, ganar tu primera medalla. También es importante que leas [ask] y [mcve] para poder mejorar tus preguntas y que sean bien recibidas por la comunidad, de esta manera favoreces a que los usuarios las respondan y te ayuden

Comment: Veo que agregas en todas las preguntas que dicen "NullPointerException" el mensaje de posible duplicado, en verdad crees que esa respuesta puede ayudar a solucionar esta pregunta y todas las que dicen "NullPointerException"? Habría que evaluar primero @NicolasOñate

Comment: Hola @Elenasys, no sé si al OP le ayudará o no, a mí me ha servido de mucho, si ya existe una respuesta, aunque puede que resulte algo abstracta y difícil de comprender, mi compromiso con la comunidad me insta a reportarlo, por suerte, es una comunidad abierta y de opiniones variadas, buscando la mejor manera de afrontar una solución ante semejantes problemas. Si no tiene tan claro mi reporte, le invito a abrir una cuestión en meta, explicando de manera más extensa su duda frente a mis acciones, de ese modo actuaremos en comunidad, podremos expresarnos más explayadamente y mejorar la comunidad

Comment: Bienvenido a Stack Overflow en español! Por favor, no uses imágenes salvo que sea absolutamente necesario. Mira por favor [aca](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/3976/324). Los errores y tu codigo deben ir como texto, siempre.

Comment: @NicolasOñate este y algunas casos de android, son los unicos casos donde esa pregunta justamente no sirve, porque son los bordes particulares donde el problema no es de codigo en si, si no que el error viene por otro lado y esta mal descripto.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

En la consola de comandos navega hasta el directorio de tu proyecto donde tienes tu fichero HolaMundo.java y ejecuta `javac HolaMundo.java` y después `java HolaMundo`. Si te da error de que no reconoce los comandos seguramente sea problema de java prueba a instalar la version mas reciente de jre y añadir el ejecutable al path del sistema operativo.

Enlaces de interés:

Cómo añadir JAVA al PATH del sistema https://java.com/es/download/help/path.xml

Descargar JAVA
https://www.java.com/es/download

Comment: Hola gracias por el aporte si me salio este error en la consola entonces me tocaría reinstalar?

C:\Users\Fabricio\eclipse-workspace\HolaMundo\src\com\romanz\holamundo> java HolaMundo.java
Hola Mundo :D

C:\Users\Fabricio\eclipse-workspace\HolaMundo\src\com\romanz\holamundo>java HolaMundo
Error: Could not find or load main class HolaMundo
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: HolaMundo

Comment: El primer comando es para compilar con `javac` en lugar de `java` y el segundo (que si es `java`) es para llamar a tu clase main. Es solo un procedimiento para descartar que tengas un problema con java, si pones java en la consola y no salta un error de que no encuentra ese comando quiere decir que tienes bien instalado java. Y lo de compilar y ejecutar desde la consola es para comprobar que realmente estas ejecutando el fichero correcto con la clase adecuada